# With AFNetworking in iOS, what is the best way to determine if a failure response is a server error or connection error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

With AFNetworking in iOS, what is the best way to determine if a failure response is a server error or connection error?

For example, if an upload fails due to a connection error, I may want to retry the upload automatically after some time interval.  Conversely, if an upload fails because of a server error, I will want to permanently stop trying the request.  (Errors where I would NOT want to retry would be most 400 and 500 errors.)

Please tell me how can I most easily determine if I'm simply seeing a connection error or if I am seeing a server error?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to include "reachability" in your analysis (e.g. don't even try connections if `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` says there's no connection, but go ahead and issue any pending requests as soon as you're notified that connection has been restored, rather than waiting some prescribed period of time).

Answer (score 0):

I use following UIImageView category. It tries to reload image after 5 sec delay.

h file:

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

@interface UIImageView (ConvenienceAdditions)

- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block;
- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block;
- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block;

@end
```

m file:

```
#import "UIImageView+ConvenienceAdditions.h"

static NSTimeInterval kDGImageReloadingAttemptInterval = 5;

@implementation UIImageView (ConvenienceAdditions)

- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [self setAutoRetryImageWithURL:url completion:nil];
}

- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block
{
    [self setAutoRetryImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil completion:block];
}

- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [self setAutoRetryImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage completion:block];
}

- (void)setAutoRetryImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage completion:(CompletionBlockCommon)block
{
    __weak typeof (self) weakImageView = self;
    [self setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        __strong __typeof(weakImageView)strongImageView = weakImageView;
        if (block){
            block(image, nil);
        }
        else{
            strongImageView.image = image;
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled){ // Check error's code
            return ;
        }
        else if (response.statusCode >= 400) // Check response's code
        {
            return;
        }
        else{
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, kDGImageReloadingAttemptInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakImageView setAutoRetryImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:placeholderImage completion:block];
            });
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Should be used following way:

```
[someImageView setAutoRetryImageWithURL:someImageURL];
```